# iOS URLSession: Some of GET requests timed out (happens only with https)

Tags: ios, timeout, urlsession

I'm sending batch of GET requests of the same type: https://server.com/some-object/{id}:

```
let urlStr: String = "https://server.com/some-object/1"
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
    (data, response, error) in

    guard error == nil else {
        print(error!)
        return
    }
    ...
}

task.resume()
```

The problem is that some of these requests fail with timeout:

> {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}

If I send 3 requests then for example 1 of them can fail. 5 requests may result in 2 failures. 15 requests ~ 6 failures... Different amount of failures each time. The same request can return data for the first time and fail next time.

I tried put these requests to concurrent OperationQueue, serial OperationQueue, without OperationQueue - no success. In serial queue each 3rd-4th request fails with timeout.

According to server logs, it receives all requests and process them without any error. But on client I have timeout.

This happens only with HTTPS. When I change address to HTTP, all requests return data.

Can anyone help me? What can be the issue?

Comment: did you update your `Info.plist` to respect ATS? - https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33)

Comment: I set NSAllowsArbitraryLoads=true to allow making HTTP requests. Though HTTPS doesn't properly work with both true or false.